# Create hybrid ELF and Mach-O binary

Tags: cross-platform, elf, mach-o

Assume I have a program built for Linux (`foo.elf`) and for OSX (`foo.macho`). I would like to distribute it in a way so that the user doesn’t have to worry about it.

Is there a way to create a file `foo` that works like `foo.elf` on Linux and `foo.macho` on OSX, maybe using some clever tricks to make the file compatible with both formats?

Comment: The two file formats are fundamentally incompatible, so if you really want to distribute only a single file, the only way I see would be to embed both binaries in a custom stub loader written in something that can run by itself on both systems, e.g. bash or Java. Also, you'd likely still have to cut the embedded binaries out and write them to temporary files at runtime in order to actually execute them.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to have a binary file that is both recognized as an ELF and a MACH-O file; this plan already breaks down in the first four bytes:

- ELF want `.ELF`, while
- MACH-O wants `0xFEEDFACE` or `0xFEEDFACF` (depending on bit width).

Assuming that the systems actually check the magic bytes, there is no way of creating a file that is both an ELF and a MACH-O file.

Comment: "it is not possible to have a binary file that is both recognized as an ELF and a MACH-O" -- that's true, but it's not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create a file foo that works like foo.elf on Linux and foo.macho on OSX

Yes, there is: [shell archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar).

Effectively, you create a tiny shell program that decides whether to run `foo.elf` or `foo.macho`, and then invokes that program after extracting it to a temporary directory. Both native executables can be stored in e.g. a compressed zip file, so the overhead of shipping the unused binary could be minimized.

> maybe using some clever tricks to make the file compatible with both formats?

That is *impossible* (as Joachim Breitner correctly explained).